# When checking Maven in Jenkins I get this error "Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been looking at this for days.

I've created an instance of Jenkins in Docker to run locally using this DockerFile -

`FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.346.2-jdk11

USER root
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
RUN usermod -a -G docker jenkins
USER jenkins

COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugin-file /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

COPY seedJob.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/seed-job/config.xml

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`

I have then installed the JDK in Jenkins

I have then installed Maven in Jenkins

I have then created a simple Pipeline to test for Maven

`pipeline {
agent any

```
tools {
    // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
    maven '3.8.6'
    jdk 'openjdk-171'
}

stages {
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
           
            sh 'mvn --version'

        }
    }
}
```

}
`
AND I get this message

"Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory"

I've tried rebuilding from Scratch, followed youtube tutorials - still nothing

(I'm also running on a Mac). Any help massively appreciated!

I expect it to return the version number of Maven

Answer (score 0):

ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 is the dynamic linker for the guest binary. If you have a dynamically linked guest binary then you need to tell the emulator about not just the binary itself but also the dynamic linker and all the dynamic libraries that the guest binary links to (usually by passing it an option to tell it about a directory which has all the libraries in the usual places they would be on the real filesystem of the guest).

For gem5 you can use --redirects and --interp-dir

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But (and I'm new to this) - where do I enter " --redirects and --interp-dir" - is this a docker thing? or is it for my Mac in general?